# Is a VLOOKUP what I need?

Tags: excel, list, loops, excel-formula, vlookup

So I get two reports each month where I'm comparing a list of invoice numbers against a sales credit list of similar numbers.

Basically I have a highly detailed report and then a simple two column report that are invoice numbers and sales credit.

I need to compare my COL A in my 2-column list against another list of numbers in COL C in the detailed report and if the numbers from COL A in the report with invoices and sales credit, then I need the "Sales Credit" to populate on the detailed report.

This is what I've come up with, but the problem is, is that not all invoices on the detailed report match so they don't have that line for "Sales Credit", but I need to keep the list in tact, even with some detailed report invoices not getting "Sales Credit".

```
=VLOOKUP($C$2:$C780,$D2:$D780,15,0)
```

But it's not working properly... I can't get it leave lines blank on the detailed report.

If someone could help me with an IF THEN loop maybe in VBA, that'd be outstanding. Thanks.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you would mock up a small sample of the two lists and show the expected results.  Please [edit] the post to include this mock up.

Comment: You current `VLOOKUP` should only look for a single value (ex.: `C2` and not `$C$2:$C780`). your lookup array should have at least 15 columns wide (ex.: `$D2:$R780` and not `$D2:$D780`) Note: this is not a necessarily a solution to your problem

Comment: The correct format for vlookup is `=vlookup(<the single cell that has the value we are looking up in the list: `C2`>, <the list like: `A:B`>, <the column from which to return the value if there is a match: `2`>, `False`)  Difficult to help more than that. Are both lists in the same tab/sheet?